# derivative as a linear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n$

where $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a fixed nonzero vector, $Df(0)$ denote the derivative of $f$ at $0$ could anyone tell me which of the following are correct?

$1. Df(0)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

$2. [(Df)(0)]a=\|a\|^2$.

$3.  [(Df)(0)]a=0$

$4. [(Df)(0)]b=a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n$ for some $b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$

I am sure $1$ is true, $(Df)(x)$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ will be a $1\times n$ collumn which is $(a_1,\dots,a_n)^T$ am i right? so  $2$ is true, and $4$ is true. am I right?

Comment: By "the derivative of f..." you mean its gradient? I mean, this is what's usually mant by $\,Df(\vec x)\;$ , if I'm not wrong

Comment: @DonAntonio $Df$ as I've seen it usually means the total derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. So it would agree here.

Comment: Now the (partial) derivative is always linear, so (1) is true *if you remove that zero there*, otherwise you only have one single number...

Comment: Usual notation for Fréchet derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) is true by definition.

Since $f$ is linear, it is easy to see that $Df(x)\delta = a^T \delta$. (Hence, in this case, $Df(0) = Df(x)$ for all $x$.

2) $Df(0) a  = a^T a = \|a\|^2$.

3) $Df(0) a = 0$ **iff** $ a = 0$.

4) $Df(0)b = a^T b$.

Comment: I'm not getting $a^Ta=||a||^2$. Can you explain please ? $aa^T=||A||^2$ that is TRUE, but how $a^Ta=||a||^2$ ?

Comment: $a$ is a column vector, so $a^T a = \sum_k a_k a_k$.

Comment: But here it is given $a=(a_1,\cdots a_n)$ row vector

Comment: I am defining it as a column vector. In any event, choose whatever convention you like and be consistent.  I think of elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as column vectors and elements of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ as row vectors.

Comment: What is $(\Bbb R^n)^*$ ? Dual space ?

Comment: @Empty: Yes. Not that there is a huge distinction in $\mathbb{R}^n$.